# How to get image from video played on a surface view?

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview

I'm trying to catch the last frame of a video played on a surface view. The video is playing from http and I can not use mediaMetaDataRetriever because mediaplayer already uses the http connection and mediaMetaDataRetriever returns null.

Are there any solutions for the "capture" of the current frame on a surfaceView?

Answer (score 0):

You can't capture the contents of a SurfaceView from an app on a stock device.

SurfaceView's surface is actually a queue of buffers with a producer-consumer relationship.  Your app is the producer, and the system compositor, called "surfaceflinger", is the consumer.  Images sent to the surface can only be read by the consumer.

If you instead play your video to a [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html), you should be able to use [getBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html#getBitmap()) to get a frame.